# Is it possible to write kafka consumer received output to a file using java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, consumer, producer

I have a Kafka Producer code written in java that writes kafka messages. And a consumer code that receives these messages.

Is it possible to write theses received messages by consumer to any text file in java.

Comment: yes. did you try to google the answer before posting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Guys,

I am able to achieve it. Once the data is received at the consumer side, then it's just a common java code you have to write.

Below is the line in ode that prints the message to the console.

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(messageAndOffset.offset()) + ": " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

You can store all the message to the String and print all at a time to the file.

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(messageAndOffset.offset()) + ": " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
completMessage += new String(bytes, "UTF-8")+"\n";
```

`new String(bytes, "UTF-8")+"\n";` contains actual message.

At last print all messages to file.

```
writeDataToFile(completMessage);
```

`writeDataToFile` contains simple java code to write a string to file.

Thank you.

Comment: Kafka stream iterators are blocking, hence when called from Java they will keep on waiting for new message and your code cannot close the FileWriter. For this you can do following:<br>
1. Change the property to lower timeout<br>
`props.put("consumer.timeout.ms","1500");`<br>
2. Now in case of timeout break the loop<br>
`val file = new File(args(0))
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
while(try{stream.iterator().hasNext()}catch {
case e:Throwable => false})
{
val record = stream.iterator.next().message()
println(record.toString())
bw.write(record.toString()) 
}
`

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing your own consumer you should include the logic to write to file in the same application. Using the prepackaged console consumer you could just pipe it to a file. For example: `kafka-console-consumer > file.txt`

Another (code-free) option would be to try [StreamSets Data Collector](http://streamsets.com) an open source Apache licensed tool which also has a drag and drop UI. It includes built in connectors for Kafka and a variety of data formats.

*full disclosure I'm a committer on this project.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Below is the working code for this.

```
package com.venk.prac;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread;

public class FileConsumer extends ShutdownableThread {

    private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> kafkaConsumer;
    private String topic;
    private String filePath;
    private BufferedWriter buffWriter;

    public FileConsumer(String topic, String filePath) {

        super("FileConsumer", false);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                KafkaProperties.KAFKA_BROKER_SERVERS_PORTS_STRING);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "FileConsumer");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

        kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<Integer, String>(properties);
        this.topic = topic;
        this.filePath = filePath;

        try {
            this.buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
        ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
        try {
            for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : consumerRecords) 
                buffWriter.write(record.value() + System.lineSeparator());
            buffWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInterruptible() {
        return false;
    }

}
```